# How to update an element of the database depending the id, with a submit button

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have this code that inserts data into a table at index, but how can I make the submit button modifystatus work? I have been trying with no results, the aim is that when I press the submit button "atendido" the table of the database column name status will be = 0, depending the on id that is updating

```
    <?php if($total>0 && $search!='') 
    {
        do { 
             echo "<tr><form method='post' action='../solicitudes/modifystatusdown.php'>
             <td style='width:20%; '><input type='hidden' name='$fila[nombre]''><input type='text'>";
             echo $fila['nombre'];
             echo "</td><td style='width:20%;'>";
             echo $fila['telefono'];
             echo "</td><td style='width:20%;'>";
             echo "<input type='Submit' name='delete' value='Atendido'></td></form></tr>";
            } 
        while ($fila=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)); 
    } ?>
```

this is the modifystatus.php

```
<?php

    $nombre = $_POST[$nombre];


    $nombre = $_GET['nombre']; 

    $link = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    if($link)
    {
        mysql_select_db("users",$link);
    }

    mysql_query("UPDATE usuarios SET status=0 WHERE nombre = '$nombre'");

?>
```

Comment: You should consider using PDO.  mysql_* are now deprecated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't give your complete logic, but it is more likely that you want to use a specific name for your input and change the value. For example:

```
<?php $nombre = $fila['nombre'] ?>
<td style='width:20%; '>
    <input type='hidden' name='nombre' value='$nombre']'><input type='text'>";
```

Then the value

```
$nombre = $_POST['nombre']
```

will contain the name.

Answer (score 0):

So why do you use:

```
$nombre = $_POST[$nombre];

$nombre = $_GET['nombre'];
```

you just need:

```
$nombre = $_POST[$nombre];
```

and stop using `mysql_` it is deprecated, use mysqli or PDO